# Watin, selecting html option list, generated by Javascript

Tags: c#, list, watin

I'm having trouble selecting a list that is mixed with javascript. The original code on the page is this:

```html
 <select id="List_1" name="List_1">
 <option value="">Select..</option>
 <option value="val_1" >Orange</option>
 <option value="val_2" >Apple</option>
 <option value="val_3" >Peach</option>
 </select>
```

But when the JS file loads, it modifies the List and when I view Generated Source, I get this:

```html
 <div tabindex="0" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="listbox" title="Fruit" class="fruit-box k-select">Select..</div>
```

And WatiN cannot find the listbox anymore..

I tried:

```
  browser.Element(Find.ById("Fruit")).Focus();
  browser.Element(Find.ById("Fruit")).Click();
```

but that didn't trigger the dropdown list to go down. Then I tried to request the page with GoToNoWait(); and then use a loop to find the list, before JS is loaded, that modifies it:

```
                while (browser.SelectLists.Count <= 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100); // wait until the first option list is loaded
                }

                foreach (WatiN.Core.SelectList a in brower.SelectLists)
                {
                    if (a.IdOrName == "Fruit")
                    {
                        a.SelectByValue("val_1");
                    }
                }
```

I can see the list showing up normal in browser (not JS) at first, but the loop hangs while the page is loading and JS gets loaded before foreach loop gets a chance to get executed..

My only solution is this:

```
                    browser.Div(Find.ByTitle("Fruit")).Focus();
                    browser.Div(Find.ByTitle("Fruit")).Click();
                    browser.Div(Find.ByTitle("Fruit")).FireEvent("onClick");
                    SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                    SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

But when using SendKeys I need to have firefox window in focus, otherwise the keystrokes get sent to whatever application I have currently open which doesn't work for me.

Is there a way to select the option list, before JS is added to it? OR is there a way to use SendKeys and point it to specific application instead of currently focused one? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that a set of LI items get generated by the javascript which can then be selected on the UI. If that is true, you might want to try this

```
Div fruitdiv = browserinstance.Div(Find.ByTitle("Fruit"));
fruitdiv.Click();
fruitdiv.KeyDown();
WatiN.Core.List autocompletelist = (WatiN.Core.List)fruitdiv.NextSibling; // or whatever the relation is
autocompletelist.WaitUntilExists();
string value = "Value to select in the list";
ListItem datavaluelistitem = autocompletelist.ListItem(Find.ByText(new Regex("^" + value + "*")));
datavaluelistitem.MouseDown();
fruitdiv.WaitForComplete();
browserinstance.WaitForComplete();
```